# Nulling all references to an object

Tags: c#

I have a class `Simple`, which contains an integer, `number`.
Using this code:

```
Simple b = new Simple();
List<Simple> list = new List<Simple>();
list.Add(b);
b.number = 6;
b = null;
Debug.WriteLine("The value of b is " + b);
Debug.WriteLine("And the value of the clown in the list is " + list[0].number);
```

The Debugs return `The value of b is` and `And the value of the clown in the list is 6`.

I can assume that by adding `b` to the `list`, then a reference to `b` is stored. Then, by nulling `b`, `list` still contains a reference to the object that was `b` and thus can print out the value of `number`.

However, if I can change a member of `b` and have that reflected by the reference stored in the list, then why doesn't the `b = null` reflect on the value of `list[0]`? I can only assume this has something to do with value and reference.

Help anyone?

Comment: This isn't really a question; it's just an illustration of how references work.  b and the list entry are references to the object.  Changing the reference doesn't change the object; only changing the object referenced changes the object.

Comment: Have you tried changing a member of `b` to see what happens?

Comment: @Fls'Zen - Isn't `b.number = 6;` changing the member?

Comment: @riktor, Whoops, sorry about that, I misread your last paragraph. :(

Comment: @antlersoft - My question was about how references work, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b` and `list[0]` are both variables that reference the same location in memory. When you set `b = null`, you're setting `b`'s reference to `null`. `list[0]` is still pointing to the original location in memory and is unchanged.

When you change a property of `b`, (for instance `b.A`) you're effectively saying

> Get whatever object b is pointing to and update property A.

When you access `A` via `list[0]`, you're saying

> Go get whatever list[0] is pointing to and get me the A property.

EDIT: As another example, if `b = someObject` and `list[0] = someObject`, setting `b = someOtherObject` will not change `list[0]`... `list[0]` is still pointing to `someObject`.

So, to answer your question, you'd have to set `b = null` and `list[0] = null` to "null" the object they're both referencing. Even that, though, doesn't do what it seems like you want. All that will do is orphan the object in memory and allow the `Garbage Collector` to clean it up whenever it gets around to it.

Comment: So I'm assuming it's impossible to access the 'base' object that `b` and `list[0]` point to, and set that to null?

Comment: @riktor -- Objects can't be null; only references can be null

Comment: @riktor: If you clear all references to an object, and call [GC.Collect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx), the piece of memory that represents that object will be freed, and the object itself will cease to exist.

Comment: Thank you both of you, I see that I have to set all references to null before I can actually remove the object.